# Hidden iframes and Google TagManager

Tags: iframe, google-tag-manager

I know that it's not a good idea to use hidden iframes (zero height, display:none, etc) for tracking users because if they are not rendered their contents usually are not called too.

So why Google TagManager uses an iframe hidden in all the possible ways (display:none, visibility:hidden, width:0, height:0)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we have no insight in Google's decision making process (plus the notion that the contents of hidden iframes are not loaded should be backed up with a source or test case).

Comment: I would be sorry if this question were off-topic, but actually I don't think so.
Anyway I'm wondering why many developers use a 1x1 iframe instead of a 0x0 iframe, if it doesn't matter

Comment: When I (or anybody) votes to close it is a statement of (my) opinion - it does not mean your's is necessarily a bad question, it's not an attack on your character and it certainly does not mean that close votes are always correct. So there is no need to defend yourself against close votes, if they are not supported by at least five persons they are irrelevant in any case. This is just to save you a few moments in the future :-).

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about tracking code for GTM:

```
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXXX');</script>
```

Which has an iframe:

```
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXXXX" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
```

This iframe is for users who don't have Javascript enabled. If client's browser has disabled JS, browser is not executing JS inside `script` tags, he is just rendering html inside `noscript` tag.

Browser will just render hidden iframe and will try to load this url.

Comment: "Browser will just render hidden iframe and will try to load this url", that's the point: some browsers don't load contents of hidden iframes!

Comment: @basellone I'm pretty sure all browsers perform the GET request to the URL specified by the `src` attribute on the iframe even if it's hidden, which is usually all that's needed for tracking.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback Mikael!
If so, do you know why usually developers use a 1x1 iframe instead of a 0x0 iframe?

Comment: @basellone My guess would be that it's a legacy from when `img` tags were used which indeed needed to be 1x1 (hence the term *tracking **pixel***) in order to be sure the browser loaded it

Comment: Thank you Mikael!